# How to change (setState) of class from appBar or bottomNavigationBar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to click a button at appBar or bottomNavigationBar (InkWell on tap) and based on my click to change what widget to be loaded at screen. Something like this example with appBar, full code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
      body: MyContent(),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const MyAppBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(50);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: Row(
        children: [
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // WHAT TO DO HERE ?
            },
            child: const Text('Text'),
          ),
          const SizedBox(width: 20),
          InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              // WHAT TO DO HERE ?
            },
            child: const Text('Image'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyContent extends StatefulWidget {
  MyContent({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MyContent> createState() => _MyContentState();
}

class _MyContentState extends State<MyContent> {
  var myChoice = 0;

  // WHAT TO DO HERE ? ADD setState() ?

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    switch (myChoice) {
      case 1:
        return const Text('You clicked TEXT');
      case 2:
        return Image.network('https://picsum.photos/250');
    }
    return const Text('Waiting for action at App Bar...');
  }
}
```

I expect to load Text or Image widget based onTap at InkWell at appBar.

What to set at onTap (where "// WHAT TO DO HERE ?" is now)? Also I guess I need to add some code inside class too (where "// WHAT TO DO HERE ? ADD setState() ?" is).

"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." ... Well, I have no idea what more to add. I wanted to post whole code, so it may be a bit longer, but better have it all, than few small pieces of code and not have idea where and what to do.